# How to find what changed in function documentation when "show changes" is missing?

Tags: documentation

I was looking at 13.2 documentation at

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn132.html

Some of the functions that have been updated do have *show changes* to click on, to highlight what actually changed, which is very useful, like this one

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html

[image]

But many others do not have *show changes*  and it just says *updated*. Here is one example https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html

[image]

My question is: How would one know what was updated in these functions if the *show changes* is missing?

Can one conclude that if *show changes* is missing, then the changes in that function are not new functionality added or API changes, but may be the updates are related to only performance and may be internal bug fixes?

Comment: I did not try but there are text comparison tools online and probably there are python packages for that as well. One  could maybe compare the before and after text. A mathematica solution might use `TextSentences` and `Complement`.